When does Matching result in an ATE vs. ATT on observational causal studies?
I have read that matching nearly always yields the $ATT$ effect, but that subclassification matching can yield the $ATE$. I am therefore wondering what is a heuristic for determining what kinds of matching lead to $ATE$ vs $ATT$ effects? For example, what does exact matching, propensity score matching, or genetic matching give?

Did you read Greifer & Stuart (2023), which directly answers this question, which I cited in my answer to your very similar previous question?

Noah's paper (linked above) answers this question in great detail. If there are parts of the paper you're struggling to understand, I'd suggest you ask a specific question and reference the section you're not getting.
